# Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ConfigurableExtension' not found

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.0, jmsserializerbundle

After installing [JMS Serializer Bundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) following the [provided instructions using the deps file](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/installation#using-the-deps-file-symfony-2-0-x), I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ConfigurableExtension' not found in /vendor/bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle/DependencyInjection/JMSSerializerExtension.php on line 30
```

The class does not exist within Symfony. I am using Symfony v2.0.17. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I try the deps method and my server refused the command
`php bin/vendors install`

So I downloaded the zip file and uploaded manually.

I declared the bundle in the appKernel and autoload files but I'm facing the same fatal error.

How can I set up this bundle ?

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded version 0.9.0 of the bundle?

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/tree/0.9.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the docs that you need to use a particular version of the bundle for Symfony 2.0.x:

```
[JMSSerializerBundle]
    git=git://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle.git
    target=bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle
    version=0.9.0
```

Comment: I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/pull/205) with a fix for the docs.